# Get all the decorated properties of a class

Tags: python

I have a class that looks like:

```
class Test(object):

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return 5

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        return 10
```

How do I get back the properties I implemented? For example, `[prop1, prop2]`.

I have tried `vars()` and `dir()` but these seem to also return hidden/special methods.

Is the only way to do this to parse through the results that don't have underscores for say `dir()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
>>>[ k for k,v in Test.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, property) ]
['prop1', 'prop2']
```

Since property is a type we can use `isinstance` to find it in the class' internal dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
def isprop(v):
    return isinstance(v, property)
propnames = [name for (name, value) in inspect.getmembers(Test, isprop)]
```